# MySQL returning double columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I ran into a problem, which I cant fix at the moment. Looked to other problems, but i'm not a hero with SQL and can't fix it.

So, I need data from multiple columns, and set

```
    SELECT 
        name, 
        m.description, 
        price 
    FROM menus m, restaurants r 
    WHERE (r.uId = m.uId) 
      AND (m.description LIKE '%broodje%') 
      OR (m.name LIKE '%broodje%') 
      AND ((r.lat BETWEEN 52.164857259112 AND 52.434653740888) 
      AND (r.lng BETWEEN 6.5249704758321 AND 6.9661533241679))
```

It works fine, but it returns 2 columns, with exact the same data. And I dont understand why its doing that? There must be a simple error in the code, or something I'm forgetting.

I hope someone can explain me what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are very unclear for what you are asking about. as I can see your query for sure returns 3 columns. So what do you mean by *double*?

Comment: So show how you `fetch` the result, you are probably using the wrong function for your needs

Comment: It's returning the same columns twice. Like this:
Broodje | Testdescription | 3.2
Broodje | Testdescription | 3.2

Comment: Try using `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` instead of `$stmt->fetch();`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Im fetching it using PHP, but it also returns this in PHPMYADMIN.

Comment: I don't know how your tables are, but check if this should be inside parenthesis `AND (m.description LIKE '%broodje%') OR (m.name LIKE '%broodje%') ` -> `AND ((m.description LIKE '%broodje%') OR (m.name LIKE '%broodje%'))`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) at this moment.

Comment: I'd go with @FelippeDuarte's suggestion

Comment: You mean two columns or two rows? If columns, which columns?

Comment: Great guys, the solution from Felippe Duarte helped me out! How is that possible?

Comment: Wrap your OR in brackets

Comment: Also look up ihow to use JOIN

Comment: Ok, I'd made a answer for that, to help you and other with same doubt. Please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your tables are, but check if this should be inside parenthesis `AND (m.description LIKE '%broodje%') OR (m.name LIKE '%broodje%')` --> `AND ((m.description LIKE '%broodje%') OR (m.name LIKE '%broodje%'))`

If you don't do that, you will fetch all data that have description like %broodje% and all data that have name like %broodje%. In your case, probably both columns in the same row have this data, that's why it's duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

I think your intended query is:

```
SELECT name, m.description, price 
FROM menus m JOIN
     restaurants r 
     ON r.uId = m.uId)
WHERE (m.description LIKE '%broodje%' OR (m.name LIKE '%broodje%') AND
      (r.lat BETWEEN 52.164857259112 AND 52.434653740888)  AND
      (r.lng BETWEEN 6.5249704758321 AND 6.9661533241679);
```

If you are getting duplicates, it is probably because you put the `JOIN` conditions in the `WHERE` clause and then mess up with parentheses.